# How to avoid moving back in playing video by using video tag in HTML5

Tags: html, controls

I would like to disable the option to move back in playing video while using HTML5 video tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Add the controls attribute the the  tag. In this solution, you **can't** control the buttons that will appear in the UI.
2. Not use the control attribute, but write your own UI (buttons, input type range, ext) that call  JS api - play(), pause() methods (and more)
3. With or without the control attribute, write your own event listeners that will listen to the  events and do whatever you want (for example, seek the video to specific time)

Resources and examples:

1. [w3schools - video/audio](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)
2. [html5 seeking](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/seeking/)
3. [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)
4. [Input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)